# Prevent extraneous formatting of apt output

Tags: apt, emacs, virtual-console

When using `apt` from "dumb" terminal (this is a code word for Emacs), it produces many lines of garbage output (it probably tries to display progress, but it doesn't work on this kind of terminal).

The same happens if I try to save this information to a file, which blows up the logs contributing no useful information.

Thus, is there a way to prevent `apt` from producing garbled output?

I've seen the SO question asking for the opposite, and I think that this behavior is new. So, if the version is important, it is: `apt 1.4.6 (amd64)`

Comment: As you do not want the output, redirect to /dev/null `sudo apt install -y foo > /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirecting apt and apt-get commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897402/redirecting-apt-and-apt-get-commands)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen who says I don't want the output? I don't want output garbled by `apt` trying to display the progress of the download.

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific on what you want and dont want and either change to apt-get for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/258219/how-do-i-make-apt-get-install-less-noisy or figure out what the "many lines of garbage output" is exactly and configure apt - https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/ and the man pages http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt.8.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/apt.conf.5.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the use in scripts, dumb terminals etc. there is `apt-get`, see [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html):

> `apt` provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some
>          options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like `apt-get`(8) and `apt-cache`(8).
>
> SCRIPT USAGE AND DIFFERENCES FROM OTHER APT TOOLS
>
> The `apt`(8) commandline is designed as an end-user tool and it may change behavior between versions. While it tries not to break backward
>          compatibility this is not guaranteed either if a change seems beneficial for interactive use.
>
> All features of `apt`(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like `apt-get`(8) and `apt-cache`(8) as well.  `apt`(8) just changes the default value of
>          some options (see `apt.conf`(5) and specifically the Binary scope). So you should prefer using these commands (potentially with some additional
>          options enabled) in your scripts as they keep backward compatibility as much as possible.

Comment: So, basically it says that it is useless inside Emacs? What a nice tool...

Comment: @wvxvw It is a very nice tool, just that Emacs doesn't seem to keep up with it. :) If you want fancy output for your package management try `aptitude` – however I don't know how far Emacs can deal with it.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Emacs uses only standard VT100 and ISO codes, while other program developers often rely on all sorts of extensions made popular by various terminals to be universal. This is why the environment variable `TERM` exists - programs sending output to console should respect it. `apt` does half the job: it checks this variable, discovers that the terminal doesn't have all the functions it wants, but only removes some of them (starts using `readline` instead of a fancy `curses` dialog windows). This is just bad programming on the side of `apt`.

Comment: @wvxvw Respect, you did the research! I don't have so much insight, but if that's true please file a bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt and let the devs know.

Answer (score 6):

There are [more differences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445384/what-is-the-difference-between-apt-and-apt-get) between `apt` and `apt-get` than the fancy progress bar, so you might want [to turn that off](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-studio-users/2016-August/010926.html) while keeping all the other differences:

```
sudo apt -o Dpkg::Progress-Fancy=0 action args...
```

Some sources show `Dpkg::Progress-Fancy="0"`, which is fine but equivalent to `Dpkg::Progress-Fancy=0` since shells don't expand `0` anyway and [the quotes are simply removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal).

You probably don't want to change this setting globally because when you run `apt` outside of Emacs you will likely want the fancy progress bar. However, you could make a shorter command that achieves the same goal, such as with an [eshell alias](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias).